# vertical and horizontal equations

Tags: math-mode

I want to write an equation like this (pic related).[image]

What a good way to achieve it in LaTeX?

*edit*: I'm referring to the vertical math relation and alignment, not to how to get the norms, the boldsymbols or the coloneqq/eqqcolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the `mathtools`, `bm`, and `graphicx` packages, with an embedded `array` environment to house the vertical subcomponent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\coloneqq' and '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macros
\usepackage{bm}        % for '\bm' macro
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for ' \rotatebox' macro

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\rotcoloneqq}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\coloneqq$}}

\begin{document}
\[
k_0 \coloneqq \norm{\bm{k}_0} 
= \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
      \norm{\bm{k}} \\
      \rotcoloneqq \\
      k
  \end{array}
=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, over @campa's because it can be generalized to arbitrarily many trees of equations without much effort. However, thank you both.